# Inequality Limits of Integration for Joint Density Function

Tags: calculus, probability, multivariable-calculus

While working to find the limits of integration for a joint PDF, I somehow keep running into an error.

$
f(x,y) = kx^3\text{ for }0\leq x\leq 3\text{ and }0\leq y\leq 2
$

While evaluating the probability that $(x,y)$ satisfies $x+y \geq3\ $ I come up with the following integral:
$$
k\int_0^3\int_0^{3-x}x^3dy dx
$$
Resulting in
$$
k(\frac {234}4-\frac {243}5)
$$

According to the solution, this is incorrect. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have

$$x + y \ge 3 \implies y \ge 3 - x \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

You also have $0 \le y \le 2$. Since $0 \le x \le 3$, then $3 -x \ge 0$, so you don't need to worry about the lower bound for $y$. Thus, the bounds for $y$ would be

$$3 - x \le y \le 2 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

As for $x$, note that $3 - x \le y$ and $y \le 2$ means $3 - x \le 2 \implies x \ge 1$. Thus, the bounds for $x$ would be $1 \le x \le 3$. Overall, this means your integral would then be

$$k\int_{1}^{3}\int_{3-x}^{2}x^3dy dx \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

I'll leave it to you to do the integration and then compare the result to the answer you're supposed to get.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

As you know, you want the intersection of the three regions shown. This shows me that your integrals should be as follows:

$$k\int\limits_{1}^3 \int\limits_{3-x}^2 x^3\mathrm{dydx}$$

By the way, the point of this exercise is that these integrals should evaluate to $1$, that way you can find the value of $k$ that makes this a legitimate joint PDF.